# Raspberry Pi 4 does not see 5GHz networks

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-4

I've got myself a new Raspberry Pi and installed Raspbian (fullest of editions) using NOOBS. During installation (i presume for package download) Raspberry clearly saw and was able to connect to my 5GHz network. Alas, when actually running an installed OS the device only sees (`iwlist wlan0 scan`) 2.4GHz networks.

How can I fix this?

Comment: network country setting is set to Ukraine and network is running on channel 40. I don't have other 5GHz networks nearby to verify if this is specific to this configuration though.

Comment: Have you seen this link? https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=229082

Comment: @Sergii Zaskaleta, I tried hard and finally give up: Raspberry PI 3 B+ 5g wifi problem:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106588/raspberry-pi-3-b-5g-wifi-problem. I am happy to chip in 200 points for a bounty.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Most of us **don't** use [NOOBS](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/92069/8697) so its operation is a mystery.

It is a violation of the licence conditions to activate a 5GHz network without setting country code, which is why it is disabled by default.

Raspbian (at least a normal installation) prompts you on initial boot to set required parameters. NOOBS probably attempts to bypass this.

Comment: is there any difference between installing Raspbian via NOOBS or directly flashing Raspbian? On the last bit, I've configured network country settings in Raspbian..

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Once Raspbian is installed there is no substantial difference, although the initial setup steps differ. There are differences due to the partitioning, but if you follow the network setup you can get the same performance. Things which rely on putting files e.g. `ssh` in the boot sector are unlikely to work.