# Disable 5Ghz Wifi-band on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+

is it possible to disable the ability to use 5Ghz for the wlan0 interface?
I only want to use 2.4 Ghz Wifi Networks.
So only 2.4Ghz Wifi is available and 5Ghz is disabled.

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this, do you have a valid reason?

Comment: Because I maybe wan't to use the Raspi in a Product for the first devices to validate if it's worth develpoing it with own Hardware. And if 5Ghz is activated I also need to get 2.4 and 5 Ghz certified.
So more like we use this first with Raspi as add-on and later it should be integrated in our Machine.

Comment: ok, I don't know sorry. Maybe find your driver and use : `modinfo -p driver_name` for a specific module parameter which would allow you to do what you want. But I doubt, because the chip, in all cases, will support 5GHz band ? [BCM43455 Preliminary Data Sheet](https://www.cypress.com/file/298786/download), maybe for the moment use another rapsberry-pi version ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy to select the frequencies you want to use. **wpa_supplicant** knows an option `freq_list`. Just add this line to your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
```

Then your WiFi will only connect to this frequencies. For some more information and other frequencies you can look at [Raspberry pi 4 b 5Ghz wifi access point problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107861/79866).