# Raspberry Pi 4B - disabling 5GHz channel

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I need help with, how to disable just 5GHz channel on raspberry pi 4B? I would like to keep 2.4GHz channel on.

Comment: Why do you want to "disable just 5GHz" - just don't use it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable 5Ghz Wifi-band on Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109203/disable-5ghz-wifi-band-on-raspberry-pi-3b)