# Connect only to 5GHZ network

Tags: networking, wifi, internet, wifi-direct

How configure the Raspberry 3 B+ to connect only to the 5GHZ network and not to the 2.4GHZ network?

Its revision 1.3

The output from `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency`

```
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable 5Ghz Wifi-band on Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/109203/disable-5ghz-wifi-band-on-raspberry-pi-3b)

Comment: unfortunately not because I need this service done the other way around. I tried it but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You miss the point! In that URL the explain how you specify 2.4GHz frequency's, do the same but change the 2,4 GHz frequencies to 5GHz!

Comment: Witch revision of Raspberry Pi 3+ do you have ? I suspect it is rev. 1.3, but please verify! And what result does `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency` produce?

Comment: That's right, I own the revision 1.3.

The result is like this when typing this command:

Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
Frequency:5.32 GHz (Channel 64)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
Frequency:5.24 GHz (Channel 48)

Comment: And to rule out that it is the problem with the same SSID on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz, run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'ESSID\|Frequency'`

Comment: okey I did it and it showed me the channel list and what next ?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to select the frequencies you want to use. `wpa_supplicant` has an option `freq_list`. Just add this line to your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
freq_list=5170 5180 5190 5200 5210 5220 5230 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700
```

Then your WiFi will only connect to those frequencies.

Ref.: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107861/79866

Comment: I tried this solution but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Did any SSID show up on both 2,4 and 5GHz?

Comment: Yes and not just once :)